# How to use ParseServer with Xamarin in 2019?

Tags: c#, xamarin, parse-server

I have an IOS app (Objective C), which uses Sashido.io implementation of Parse, which works perfectly. Now I want to develop an Android app, which should connect to the same ParseServer.

Since I am familiar with C# and Visual Studio (Mac version) is my second home, I thought that Xamarin was the way to go - but I might be wrong;

For the last couple of days, I have been struggling to get *any* Xamarin multiplatform projects to connect to my parse server.

I have tried the SharedLibrary approach (.NET Standard2) with the Parse.NETStandard2 (v2.0.0) Nuget-package, but I had no luck with that, it crashes every time I would try to do anything Parse-releated - stack trace hinting some library is missing, but I am unable to locate the missing link.
I have now tried the Multiplatform-library with the Parse (v1.7.0) nuget-package as well, but with no grether luck;

The following code crashes with Parse-authorization error.
I have double/tripled checked both the ApplicationId and the Server-url.

```
        ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
        {
            ApplicationId = "Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            WindowsKey = "undefined",
            Server = "https://pg-app-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scalabl.cloud/1/"
        });
        try
        {
            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.LogInAsync("realusername", "realpassword").Result;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("EXCEPTION: {0}", ex.Message));

        }
```

I have googled everything remotely related to my issue, but I haven't found any newer blogs or tutorials - letting me to believe that either, it is normally not an issue or that Xamarin and parse-server simply is a no go.

I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction for getting an Xamarin-app to connect to Parse.
I am not too familiar with the multiplatform environment.

Comment: What is the exception/stacktrace?

Comment: System.AggregationException as far as I remember.

Comment: You need to the full exception (with the inner exception), otherwise anyone is just guessing as to what your problem is...

Comment: Inner exception:
{System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetModuleFileName   at (wrapper managed-to-native) StandardStorage.StorageUtilities.GetModuleFileName(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,System.Text.StringBuilder,int)   at StandardStorage.StorageUtilities.GetModuleFil…}

Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/300

Comment: Thank you for the link @SushiHangover - my issues has not been 100% resolved though - I am still unable to connect to my parse-server from xamarin.
In my opinion it just proves that Parse-server has lost its momentum, and I will probably choose another solution.